# How to put pagination on search result using symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

I am working on a project using symfony2. I already have my search function and it is already working. But what I want is to have pagination on the search results since there are times that there are a lots of data being retrieve. How can I possibly do it?

Here is my code :

```
public function searchAction (Request $request) {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $data = $request->get('search');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery (
            'SELECT a,b,c FROM SampleBundle:transactDetail a
            JOIN a.transact b
            JOIN b.transactType c
            WHERE b.pNumber LIKE :data
            OR b.senderId LIKE :data'
        )
        ->setParameter('data', "%$data%");
        $result = $query->getResult();

        if ($result == null ) {
            return $this->render('SampleBundle:Sample:noresult.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->render('SampleBundle:Sample:search.html.twig', array('result' => $result));
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can somebody help me?

Comment: You can use KnpPaginator or FantaPaginator they have adapters for Doctrine, Propel and other. Or just use DoctrinePaginator (build in doctrine component) but it only paginates, it doesn't have a renderer for pagination html component.

Comment: @aizele You can use [PagerFantaBundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle)

Comment: I am just using "use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator". How can I implement it?

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski : how can I do it in Doctrine Paginator? Can you help me?

Comment: @Roukmoute: how can I separate it in controller and repository? can you further help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of your code with [Paginator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) :

```
public function searchAction(Request $request, $firstResult = 0, $maxResults = 100)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data = $request->get('search');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a,b,c FROM SampleBundle:transactDetail a
            JOIN a.transact b
            JOIN b.transactType c
            WHERE b.pNumber LIKE :data
            OR b.senderId LIKE :data'
    )
        ->setParameter('data', "%$data%")
        ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
        ->setMaxResults($maxResults);

    $result = new Paginator($query);

    if ($result == null) {
        return $this->render('SampleBundle:Sample:noresult.html.twig');
    }

    return $this->render('SampleBundle:Sample:search.html.twig', array('result' => $result));
}
```

And if you would like to count the total just `count($result);`.
Paginator has Countable et IteratorAggregate interfaces.
So you can loop on your result without problem.

Comment: how about the routing? do I still need to do something like this: sample_search : pattern : /search/{$firstResult} defaults: { _controller: "SampleBundle:Sample:search", firstResult: 1 } ?

Comment: can I move my code (query) to repository so it will not be too long in my controller? Is it possible? How can I do it?  thanks :)

Comment: how can I display the navigation for pagination in view?